# How do I correctly implement a Set in a class as a property?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Suppose I have the following as an example:

```
  TDelphiIDECompatibility = (
    Delphi1,
    Delphi2,
    Delphi3);
```

From a class, how could I implement the above correctly as a property?

---

The idea is that in my component I want to have a field that will allow you to select True or False for certain elements in a Set.

I tried to declare like this without much luck:

```
TMyClass = class
private
  FIDECompatibility: Set of TDelphiIDECompatibility;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;

  property IDECompatibility: TDelphiIDECompatibility read
    FIDECompatibility write FIDECompatibility;
end;
```

The error message been:

> Incompatible types: 'TDelphiIDECompatibility' and 'Set'

---

The quick way I know is to just declare them as regular booleans, like so:

```
private
  FDelphi1Compatible: Boolean;
  FDelphi2Compatible: Boolean;
  FDelphi3Compatible: Boolean;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;

  property Delphi1Compatible: Boolean read
    FDelphi1Compatible write FDelphi1Compatible;
end;
```

But I don't really like having it like that when I can have them defined in a Set/Enumeration?

What should I be doing to declare it properly instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Take an inspiration e.g. from `Anchors` property. `Anchors` is of type `TAnchors` which is defined as a `set of TAnchorKind`.

Comment: What's missing is the set type declaration: `  TDelphiIDECompatibilitySet = set of TDelphiIDECompatibility;` The property and the backing field can be of this type.

Comment: @TLama I have done it and seems to work now thanks, will show it in an answer unless you want to put an answer in

Comment: The compiler's message told you **exactly** what your error was. Compilation error messages are a developers best friend - spend a few moments to try and understand them - it will save you time in the long run.  :)

Comment: @Vector that was just the latest error message I had, when I was trying other ways I got more errors and sometimes even with the help of the compiler messages its not always clear what the problem/solution is.

Comment: _sometimes even with the help of the compiler messages its not always clear what the problem/solution is_ - Agreed, although I think in Delphi the messages are usually pretty good, such as in the example you cited in your question. If you work in C++, it's something else entirely... for me at least, often enough the compiler messages are harder to figure out than the problem in your code... :)

Comment: @Vector Delphi is hard enough for me at the best of times, I dabbled in C++ once many years ago and have never went back, way too raw and complex for me!

Comment: @Blobby - Agreed, C++ is very difficult compared to Object Pascal. I forced myself to learn it because  in my early work with Delphi when it was first released, it was important for me to understand the Windows API well. And it would have been an impossible task to learn it on my own if i had not already known Object Pascal fairly well.  As it is, I don't really know C++ very well at all [ As the C++ people around here will be happy to tell you... :) ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From TLama's comment I looked at the Delphi source for Anchors and came up with the solution here:

```
TDelphiIDECompatibilityKind = (
  Delphi1,
  Delphi2,
  Delphi3);

TDelphiIDECompatibility = set of TDelphiIDECompatibilityKind;
```

And the class:

```
private
  FIDECompatibility: TDelphiIDECompatibility;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;

  property IDECompatibility: TDelphiIDECompatibility read
    FIDECompatibility write FIDECompatibility;
end;
```

Comment: You got it. Just note your constructor should be: `constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;`

Comment: @CraigYoung thanks :) But do I still need to have that if its just a regular class? I thought that only applied if it was a TComponent derived class?

Comment: No, but your question did say you wanted it in a component. I should have clarified. And you can of course also choose to use a non-component constructor as an additional constructor in your component.

Comment: @CraigYoung yes it is for a component, but I have separate classes like this one outside the main component. The main component does have the `Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;` that is one thing I actually know :) But thanks for mentioning anyway, glad to see people looking out for one another ;)

Comment: FWIW, as @CraigYoung noted in his deleted answer, the convention is to call the enum `TDelphiIDECompatibility` (IOW, a singular noun) and the corresponding set `TDelphiIDECompatibilities` (its plural).